# Save data to the local storage of another domain with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dns, local-storage, cross-domain

I have an application that has three domains, one is the main one where the user logs in, and when he does he's redirected to another one of the domains, and i want to make it so when he is redirected he's already logged in.

Normally to log in i save the token i receive in the localStorage, but when i do this now it saves on the localStorage of the main domain, but i want to save the token in the redirected domain so he can automatically login.

So basically, how do i save this token in the localStorage of the other domain?

Comment: I would in every way hope that browser's explicitly and strictly don't allow this.  The potential for malicious use seems... high.

Comment: A common backend between the domains with properly configured CORS and where the authorization and redirects can all be securely managed in the same place is the best option here.

Comment: You can't write localStorage for another domain. But you can write a Secured Cookie on the root domain using the [`Domain` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent) in the cookie, so it will be available for any sub-domain sharing the same root domain.